# Evillious Chronicles: What is the reference / wordplay with the "United States of Maistia"?

Tags: vocaloid

In regards to the Evillious Chronicles, what is the reference / wordplay with the "United States of Maistia", the counterpart to the United States of America?

The other countries are mainly based on other countries and demons... [(Vocaloid Wiki Trivia for Seven Deadly Sins)](https://vocaloid.fandom.com/wiki/Seven_Deadly_Sins#Trivia)

- Asmodean - Saudi Arabia/Turkey (Asmodeus)
- Beelzenia - Roman Empire (Spain and Italy) (Beelzebub)
- Lucifenia - France (Lucifer)
- Elphegort - Germany (Belphegor)
- Levianta - Russia (Leviathan)
- Marlon - Great Britain (Mammon)
- Jakoku - Japan (Meaning [Snake Land](https://theevilliouschronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Jakoku#Trivia))
- Union State of Evillious - European Union (Evil)
- United States of Maistia - United States
- Tasan - Hungary ([Satan?](https://theevilliouschronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Tasan#Trivia))

Comment: Possibly Mastema?